# Site Icon upload and display in a theme

Tags: uploads, logo

Sorry for my stupid question,I am new to wordpress development.

I want to upload the site logo and icon via my theme's option page.Anyone can help me with a code snippet

Thank you!

Comment: I only want the logo upload to be on option page of the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon

Comment: This good for an already uploaded site icon ,but I also want to upload it via setting page of the theme not via media